# Singly linked list abstraction in ES5 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Below is the code for, Singly linked list implementation,

```
function List(){
    this.start=null; 
    this.end=null;
}

List.makeNode=function(){ 
    return {data:null,next:null};
};

List.prototype.add=function (data){
    if(this.start===null){ 
        this.start=List.makeNode(); 
        this.end=this.start;
    }else{
        this.end.next=List.makeNode(); 
        this.end=this.end.next; 
    }
    this.end.data=data; 
};

List.prototype.traverse = function(){
    var current = this.start;
    while (current !== null) {
        current = current.next; 
    }
};

List.prototype.insertAsFirst = function(d) {
    var temp = List.makeNode();
    temp.next = this.start; 
    this.start = temp; 
    temp.data = d; 
};
List.prototype.delete = function(data) {
    var current = this.start; 
    var previous = this.start; 
    while (current !== null) { 
        if (data === current.data) { 
            if (current === this.start) { 
                this.start = current.next; 
                return; 
            } 
            if (current == this.end) this.end = previous; 
            previous.next = current. next; 
            return; 
        } 
        previous = current; 
        current = current.next; 
    } 
};
List.prototype.insertAfter = function(t, d) { 
    var current = this.start; 
    while (current !== null) { 
        if (current.data === t) { 
            var temp = List.makeNode(); 
            temp.data = d; 
            temp.next = current.next; 
            if (current == this.end) this.end = temp; 
                current.next = temp; 
                return; 
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
};
List.prototype.item=function(i){ 
    var current = this.start; 
    while (current !== null) {
        i--; 
        if(i===0) return current; 
        current = current.next; 
    } 
    return null;
};
List.prototype.each = function(f) {
    var current = this.start; 
    while (current !== null) { 
        f(current); 
        current = current.next;
    }
};
```

From the above code,

1) Is `List` a proper abstraction?

2) Does `List` ensure encapsulation?

3) Is the usage of `List.prototype` justified?

4) Does `makeNode` justified as static function?

Comment: You do realized the JS arrays are (normally) implemented as Linked Lists under the hood, right?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha  JS array implemented as linked list will degrade insert operation performance. Any reference on this info?

Comment: @overexchange I'd worry more about getting things done over some micro-optimization.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha this is incorrect. See https://www.quora.com/How-are-javascript-arrays-implemented-internally
Javascript arrays are more like C++ vector or Java ArrayList when they are dense. When they are sparse they're essentially hashmaps, they're still not linked lists, ie performance will always be better than O(n) for retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to track the end of the list. You can just check that you've reached it if an element's next is `null`.

`makeNode` doesn't do anything. Every time you use it you set `data` instantly after, so `data` should be a parameter. Setting `next` to `null` isn't that useful because if you don't change it you can simply check `node.next === undefined` and get the same thing, while using less memory.

Try

```
function MakeNode(data) {
  return { data: data };
}
```

In general it's not that useful to separate the `node` and `list` abstractions. If you want a list just pass around the first node of the list. It makes many algorithms much simpler to read and write.

I'd start with

```
function Node(data, next) {
  this.data = data;
  this.next = next;
}
```

This sets `next` to `undefined` if you just do `new Node(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything JonathanR says is true, but also

- The `traverse` function does nothing useful
- You are finding an element based on `data` in 3 different places, that should be a separate function
- `insertAtFirst` -> should really be `unshift` to be familiar
- `add` should be `push`
- `each` probably should be `forEach`

As I went thru the code I maintained a version that I would write, and I realized I was missing a ton of test cases ( I think you are as well ), such as deleting the first node if there is only 1 node. In that case you need to set `this.end` to `null`. You need a lot of test cases! That is why I was hesitant to show my version, since I just know some use cases are missing. But if you check it out, it might give you ideas on how to approach this differently.

```
    function List(){
      this.start=null; 
      this.end=null;
    }

    function List.makeNode = function makeNode(data, next) {
      return {data:data,next:next};
    }

    List.prototype.push = function add(data){
      var node = List.makeNode(data);
      if(!this.start){ 
        this.start=node;
      }else{
        this.end.next=node; 
      }
      this.end = node; 
    };


    List.prototype.unshift = function unshift(data) {
      this.start = List.makeNode( data , this.start );
    };

    List.prototype.get = function get(data){
      var current = this.start; 
      while( current ){
        if( current.data === data ){
        return data;
        }else{
        current = current.next;
      }
      }
    }

    List.prototype.getPrior = function getPrior(data){
      var current = this.start,
        previous;
      while( current ){
        if( current.data === data ){
          return previous;
        }else{
          previous = current;
          current = current.next;
        }
      }
    }

    List.prototype.remove = function remove(data) {
      var previous = this.getPrior(data);
      if(!previous){
        this.start = this.start.next;
      } else if( this.end.data == data ){
        this.end = previous;
        previous.next = null;
      } else {
        previous.next = previous.next.next;
      }
    };

    List.prototype.insertAfter = function insertAfter(target, data) { 

        var target = this.get(target); 
        if( target == this.end ){
          this.end = this.end.next = List.makeNode(data)
        }else{
          target.next = List.makeNode( data , target.next ); 
        }
    };
    List.prototype.item = function item(i){ 
        var current = this.start; 
        while (current !== null) {
            if(!--i) return current; 
            current = current.next; 
        } 
    };

    List.prototype.forEach = function forEach(f) {
        var current = this.start; 
        while (current) { 
            f(current); 
            current = current.next;
        }
    };
```

- Is it a proper abstraction is an interesting question, I would say no. It seems more distinct rather than abstract ;)
- Did you encapsulate? No, all the data can be gotten without using any of the provided functions
- `List.prototype` justified -> Absolutely
- `makeNode` as a static function, meh. Honestly if you think about it, the result of `List` and `makeNode` are very very similar, I would (ab)use that.